# Camunda for storing data

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

In camunda, if a lot of data are associated with a task, should we try to capture the data in the task itself? or the data has to be stored in a separate table and use Camunda only to track the status?

For instance: In the below process, as part of registration, I want to capture (name, address, state, country, etc) then these data should be embedded somehow in camunda registration task itself? (or) a separate table to store the data?

What is the best practice?

[image: BMPN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data which are required for process execution can be stored in camunda data store. Other data should be stored on separate tables. Below post have a detailed explanation

https://forum.camunda.org/t/camunda-data-storage/16365